# stringbuilder with if in appendformat

Tags: c#

I would like to have a short if in a string builder AppendFormat so that I can add two different colors to a td when the qty are not the same.

Thats my try to do this:

```
foreach (var item in dataObj.Ord.LineColl)
{
    builder.AppendFormat(
        @"<tr><td align='right'> {0}</td>
          <td> {1}</td>
          <td> {2}</td>
          <td align='right'> {3} {4}</td>" +
            item.OrdQt == item.ShQt? 
            @"<td align='right' bgcolor='#FF000'> {5} {6}</td>" :
            @"<td align='right' bgcolor='#FFFFFFFF'> {5} {6}</td>"
            ,item.LineNumber, item.Product.Code, item.Product.Description,
                    item.OrdQt, item.OrdQt.Code,
                    item.QtyMes, item.OrdQt.Code,
                    item.ShQt, item.OrdQt.Code);
}
```

The problem is that the following error occurs:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'`

Comment: You already did that? what is wrong with your code can you clarify it more?

Comment: Problem with operator precedence "+" will evaluated before "==" and == compares string and bool.
    
`( item.OrdQt == item.ShQt? 
            @"<td align='right' bgcolor='#FF000'> {5} {6}</td>" :
            @"<td align='right' bgcolor='#FFFFFFFF'> {5} {6}</td>")`

will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the color to another variable and then include it in your `AppendFormat`. Note that there are more variables in that than there are in the string, I'm not sure which are right based on your snippet

```
foreach (var item in dataObj.Ord.LineColl)
{
    var color = (item.OrdQt == item.ShQt) ? '#ff000' : '#ffffff';

    builder.AppendFormat(
        @"<tr><td align='right'>{0}</td>
         <td>{1}</td>
         <td>{2}</td>
         <td align='right'>{3} {4}</td>
         <td align='right' bgcolor='{9}'> {5} {6}</td>", 
            item.LineNumber, item.Product.Code, item.Product.Description,
            item.OrdQt, item.OrdQt.Code, item.QtyMes, item.OrdQt.Code,
            item.ShQt, item.OrdQt.Code, color);
}
```

Comment: Also, opening `<tr>`, but no closing `<tr>`. There are likely other issues with this snippet, but to get the color that'll give you the idea